# Excel SES retornando #N/D

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou criando uma verificação para saber se o valor do *peso* esta entre:

```
=SES(FRETES!$I$3>1<30;21,75;FRETES!$I$3>31<50;27,91;FRETES!$I$3>51<70;35,54;FRETES!$I$3>71<100;47,72;FRETES!$I$3>101<150;76,27;FRETES!$I$3>151<200;116,01;FRETES!$I$3>201;0)
```

Mas sempre retorna

> #N/D

Agradeço quem poder ajudar.

Comment: Fala Tiago, se a resposta abaixo atendeu não esqueça de marcar como resposta de sua questão para ajudar outros no futuro.

Answer (score 2):

O erro está na forma como está fazendo os testes com o `SES()`:

```
=SES(FRETES!$I$3>1<30....
```

A formatação correta do `SES()` seria:

```
=SES(VALOR_TESTADO=VALOR_1;RESULTADO_1;VALOR_TESTADO=VALOR_2;RESULTADO_2)
```

Analisando sua fórmula, ficaria algo assim, usando no teste o `E()`:

```
=SES(E(FRETES!$I$3>1;FRETES!$I$3<30);21,75;E(FRETES!$I$3>=30;FRETES!$I$3<50);27,91)
```

Favor notar que coloquei o `>=`, pois da forma como estava não daria o resultado se o peso fosse exatamente 30, por exemplo.

Veja outro exemplo aqui:

http://excelguru.com.br/excel-2/novas-funcoes-excel-365/

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer o teste.

Comment: Evert, você é fera!

Comment: =) Valeu Leandro!!